# Using WebApi Default owin Authentication from a different project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm using WebApi with default (auto generated) owin authentication (with entity framework)

I need to separate the authentication to different project (DAL)
and also use the users generated in other tables in the database

I hope I explained myself correctly, tell me if not

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just noticed that it creates

```
ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

automatically in the Models folder

So all we need to do is move ApplicationDbContext to the DAL project and update all references to it accordingly